# asp.net repeater data after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

In my .ascx control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server">
            <%# Eval("Name") %>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Postback" onclick="btnGo_Click" />
```

And in the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack){
        var products = (from p in context.Products
                        select p).Take(30);

        rptProducts.DataSource = products;
        rptProducts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And i'm wondering why my repeater looses it's data after i click that button.(postback)

Comment: It shouldn't be.  What's going on inside `btnGo_Click`?

Comment: What do you mean "the repeater looses it's data"  Does it go blank, meaning all controls are wiped out?  Are you trying to access Repeater values in the button click event?

Comment: In the button event i'm doing nothing. It's just there to fire the postback. What i mean by losing the data, is that all the rows in the repeater are gone after the postback.

Answer (score 4):

Bind the `Repeater` in `OnInit` instead.

http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/repeaters-and-lost-data-after-postback-viewstate/

**Edit**: I assume that you're handling the `UserControl`'s `Load` event which gets raised **after** the `Page`'s `Load` event. Dynamic controls must be created in Page_Load at the latest.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1191194.aspx

So either bind your Repeater in Page_Init or -what i would recommend:

Provide a public function like `BindData` that can be called from your page's load-event. This is also the recommended way since the page is the controller of the UserControl.

```
public void BindData()
{
    var products = (from p in context.Products
                    select p).Take(30);

    rptProducts.DataSource = products;
    rptProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: That may or may not be relevant depending on some unanswered questions, and he does have the binding within an if(!Page.IsPostback)  block, so the issue isn't that the repeater is rebinding on postback and losing values that way.

Comment: Moving the binding to the OnInit didn't make any difference. I see that there is more discussion on this topic all over the internet. Could it be that this behavior is by design? Or a bug?

Comment: @TysHTTP: Have you tried the method-approach? I must admit that i haven't heard of such behaviour before, but i'm binding my usercontrols always from their controller(f.e. page).